# Swift to Kotlin: Protocol to Interface, with generics

Tags: swift, generics, interface, kotlin, protocols

Been working at this small code translation over the past couple days.  It's really just Kotlin syntax stumping me...

Swift:

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    associatedtype VMType = BaseViewModel
    var viewModel: VMType { get set }
}

public class BaseViewModel {
    var moduleModel: ModuleModel
    required public init(moduleModel: ModuleModel) {
        self.moduleModel = moduleModel
    }
}
```

Here's what I've brought over to Kotlin, (it's the Protocol to interface stumping me, primarily with regards to the generics)

Kotlin:

```
interface BaseInterface<VMType> {    // Not sure if this is correct
    // protocol code...
}

class BaseViewModel(internal var moduleModel: ModuleModel)
```

I believe I have structured my BaseViewModel properly, but if that needs adjustment I am all ears, as well.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a swift programmer so correct me if I'm wrong. Is your protocol type bounded to the BaseViewModel class? If yes you can declare a bounded type in your interface as well.

```
interface BaseInterface<T : BaseViewModel>
```

And also, since you are bounded on the BaseViewModel class, be sure to set it as inheritable by adding the `open` modifier.

```
open class BaseViewModel(var moduleModel: ModuleModel)
```

Comment: Excellent - this appears to satisfy the syntax.  I have not tested the code just yet, as it requires other pieces to come together before I can.  That said, my current issue has been resolved with your input.

Thanks for the 'open' catch, as well!  I would have blown that, totally missed it.